# How to render ListItems in React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner learning React + Redux. I'm working to build my first List/ListItems and running into an error. Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

const CatList = ({cats}) => {
  return (
    {cats.map(cat => (
      <li key={cat.id}>
        {cat.name}
      </li>
    ))}
  );
};

CatList.propTypes = {
  cats: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default CatList;
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Error in ./src/components/cats/CatList.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (7:9)

   5 | const CatList = ({cats}) => {
   6 |   return (
>  7 |     {cats.map(cat => (
     |          ^
   8 |       <li key={cat.id}>
   9 |         {cat.name}
  10 |       </li>

Error
 @ ./src/components/cats/CatsPage.js 20:15-35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components should return single element. Please try this (just wrap your markup in aditional div):

```
const CatList = ({cats}) => {
  return (
    <div>
       {cats.map(cat => (
         <li key={cat.id}>
           {cat.name}
         </li>
       ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```